Unable to publish Reactjs Website on GitHub Pages: Error 404
I am creating a website using ReactJS and am trying to publish on github using github pages. However I am having issues:

I've seen all 404-related questions here with no luck.
My package.json:

{
  "name": "mywebsite_(copy)",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://mywebsite.github.io/mywebsite", 
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "serve": "^14.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "live": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ext": "js css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1"
  }
}


Here are my routes in App.js:
<Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
      <Route path="/aboutus" element={<AboutUs />} />
      <Route path="/appointment" element={<Form/>} />
</Routes>

I've tried changing in package.json:

homepage property e.g
"homepage": "https://mywebsite.github.io/mywebsite"
OR
"homepage": "./"
OR
"homepage": "https://github.com/mywebsite/mywebsite.github.io"

private property
"private": false
OR
"private": true


So I'm not sure what the issue is. Perhaps issues with the Router or absolute links rather than relative links in build/index.html?

In your Github repo settings, under 'Pages'->'Build and deployment'->'Branch', you need to tell Github what publishing source branch you want to use for the pages site. Otherwise, you'll get a fallback 404 page, because Github doesn't know what source branch to serve for the page content.
You can read more about that here in the Github pages documentation.

yes, I'm deploying gh-pages using the correct branch
